# How can we create corrugated material

Tags: materials

I have created the side material and want to make the edge thickness material of the corrugated board.

[image]

I want to make with material not with texture. So how can i create the wave like shape. Is it possible. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to make geometry for this? Or  a _procedural_ texture (No images)?

Comment: @RobinBetts procedural textural can do. Because i do not want to unwrap and set on the image. More than 50 parts i have to just apply the edge material. Thanks